# Like and Unlike System in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a community site for high school students. I am trying to implement a like and unlike system using PHP. Heres what I have got :

- A table named `likes` in MySQL with 3 columns namely app_id VARCHAR(32), user VARCHAR(12), dormant VARCHAR(6).
- UNIQUE(app_id,user)

When a person likes a page on my site, a row is either inserted or updated in the `likes` table with `dormant = false`.

When a person unlikes a page, the row present is again updated with `dormant = true`. This is an alternative to deleting the row as it is a bit intensive for a speedy work of likes and unlikes.

I want to know, if I should go for deleting the row instead of updating it, when someone unlikes the page.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why is you user a `string` and not an `integer`?

Comment: Maybe you could just *soft delete* them: Set a flag like `deleted = 1`. Than later you can track all changes of likes.

Comment: @insertusernamehere, yeah that seems innovative. I can go for a a soft delete. And later schedule a cron job for deleting the rows after a set period of time, maybe every weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Dont Delete the row. Every data you can gather its a valuable data point. 
I would say you should create a new record for every unlike also.

These data will be usefull to you in the future to figure out user behaviour.

Some ppl might like smth now and then unlike it , then like it again and so on.

Maybe in the future u would like to see why so many people who liked an item suddely unliked it then liked it again.

So i say gather as much data as you can.

Comment: Just to add to the subject , all you need in your likes table is : id, user_id, item_id, like (0,1), date_created

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like premature optimization. Don't do that.

Design your application as you want to use it /as it should work. When it gets busy, find out the bottlenecks and fix them.

If you want to design your application for scalability to the millions, consider using a different database engine / programming platform altogether.

Comment: Please explain it a bit more. Should I delete the row on unlike?

Comment: If I would design the database, I would probably delete it. On the other hand, some kind of logging would be nice too. So you can see when somebody liked or unliked something. Note though, that it is hard to make the decision without more information. You cannot simplify application design to simple decisions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't record the number of user liked or unliked the pages. In this case, **LIKES** should be a **many** table and there should be another table called APPS (or any name you wish) to store pages:

```
**USER**
+---------+-------+-----+
| user_id |  name | ....|
+---------+-------+-----+
|    1    |  ...  | ... |
+---------+-------+-----+
|    2    |  ...  | ... |
+---------+-------+-----+

**APPS**
+---------+-------+-----+
| app_id  |  name | ....|
+---------+-------+-----+
|    1    |  ...  | ... |
+---------+-------+-----+
|    2    |  ...  | ... |
+---------+-------+-----+

**LIKES**
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
| like_id |user_id|  app_id  | is_liked |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
|    1    |  1    |    2     |   1      |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
|    2    |  1    |    3     |   0      |
+---------+-------+----------+----------+
```

Where you can toggle if the user click like`( is_liked = 1)` or unlike`( is_liked = 0)` the page